# Counterexample: Two groups $H$ and $G$, with surjective homomorphismus

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

So I need to find a counter-example, i.e. I need to find two groups $H$ and $G$, with $N$ being normal subgroup of $G$, with a **NON**-surjective Homomorphism $\phi: G \rightarrow H$, such that $\phi(N)$ is **NOT** normal subgroup of H.

I know for sure, that H isn´t supposed to be abelian group, but I am not sure which one to take!
I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Hint: take a non-abelian simple group $H$, and take $G=N$ any proper subgroup of $H$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every group homomorphism $\Bbb Z\to S_3$ which maps $1$ into an odd permutation.

Comment: Thank you! Should I consider $\mathbb{Z}$ with Multiplication or Addition?

Comment: Addition; also a multiplicative infinite cyclic group works

Comment: shouldn't a group homomorphism map the identity into the identity?

Comment: You are right, I mean 1, fixed the typo, thank'you

Comment: How about $\phi(k) = (1 \: 2 \: 3)^k$?

Comment: Yeah, this is a good counter example!